# Mongodb Or query with two arrays

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying to perform an ***or*** query in MongoDB.

I have two array

```js
firstNames = ['John', 'Tim','Joey']
lastNames = ['Alex', 'Smith', 'Mac']
```

I want to perform a query like

```js
{$or: [{firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Alex'}, {firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith'}, {firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Mac'}, {firstName: 'Tim', lastName: 'Alex'} ... ]}
```

I tried

1.

```js
Users.find({firstName: {$in: firstNames}, lastName: {$in: lastNames} })
```

2. 

```js
Users.find({$or:[{firstName: {$in: firstNames}}, {lastName: {$in: lastNames} }]})
```

but this is wrong I guess. Can someone provide a better solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create array of tuples using `$zip`. `$match` by `$in` to find expected records.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "names": {
        "$zip": {
          "inputs": [
            [
              "John",
              "Tim",
              "Joey"
            ],
            [
              "Alex",
              "Smith",
              "Mac"
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        "$in": [
          [
            "$firstName",
            "$lastName"
          ],
          "$names"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  // cosmetics
  {
    "$project": {
      names: false
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/khQ-_AF-x9Y) for your reference.